# Java Print the first and last integers in the permutations

Tags: java

I am trying to take the first and last number in each array and find the sum of the 2 and print it off in console. Some guidance? Not exactly sure how to do it thanks! This is what I have so far it just prints off the arrays.

```
public class Permutations {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<Integer> permutation = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Collections.shuffle(permutation);
        }
        System.out.println("List 1 " + permutation);
        System.out.println("List 2 " + permutation);
        System.out.println("List 3 " + permutation);
        System.out.println("List 4 " + permutation);
        System.out.println("List 5 " + permutation);
        System.out.println("List 6 " + permutation);
        System.out.println("List 7 " + permutation);
        System.out.println("List 8 " + permutation);
        System.out.println("List 9 " + permutation);
        System.out.println("List 10 " + permutation);

    }
}

//print off
    List 1 [2, 3, 6, 10, 1, 4, 7, 9, 8, 5]
    List 2 [2, 3, 6, 10, 1, 4, 7, 9, 8, 5]
    List 3 [2, 3, 6, 10, 1, 4, 7, 9, 8, 5]
    List 4 [2, 3, 6, 10, 1, 4, 7, 9, 8, 5]
    List 5 [2, 3, 6, 10, 1, 4, 7, 9, 8, 5]
    List 6 [2, 3, 6, 10, 1, 4, 7, 9, 8, 5]
    List 7 [2, 3, 6, 10, 1, 4, 7, 9, 8, 5]
    List 8 [2, 3, 6, 10, 1, 4, 7, 9, 8, 5]
    List 9 [2, 3, 6, 10, 1, 4, 7, 9, 8, 5]
    List 10 [2, 3, 6, 10, 1, 4, 7, 9, 8, 5]
```

Comment: There is only one list in your example.

Comment: I don't quite understand the print off has 10?

Comment: Because you have 10 `System.out.println` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using [List.get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-)

Then you could simply do

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Collections.shuffle(permutation);
    System.out.println("List " + (i + 1) + " " + permutation.get(0) + " " + 
         permutation.get(9)  + " sum is " + (permutation.get(0) + permutation.get(9)));
}
```

of course better to use length of Array rather then `9`

Comment: List 17 5 sum is 12
List 210 2 sum is 12
List 33 8 sum is 11
List 49 5 sum is 14
List 53 4 sum is 7
List 65 1 sum is 6
List 72 7 sum is 9
List 88 1 sum is 9
List 96 3 sum is 9
List 107 1 sum is 8

Comment: that was the output I got but I would like it in the format of Sum of first and last:

Comment: Sorry I have added a blank space, so that `'(i + 1)` does not get added to `get(0)` - please try again.

Comment: I am sure you can modify it to print as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different solution for summing certain elements for your interest:

```
IntStream.of(0, 9).map(permutation::get).sum();
```

The potential advantage of this is that it's easy to expand the items you want to sum or to filter or map them without changing the structure of the solution.